# Why does my .ajax request report ABORTED in Firebug?

Tags: jquery, firebug

I've got the following code

```
    $(function(){
    $("#AddMaps").submit(function(){

        var $form = $('#AddMaps');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test_multiple.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                //alert(data);
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#ajax-panel').empty();
                if (data.response != "Success"){
                    $('#ajax-panel').append('Error Occurred');
                }
                else {
                    $('#ajax-panel').append('File(s) Uploaded');
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                // Failed Request; Freak out
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
```

When this event fires, Firebug reports that this event is Aborted. Additionally, in `beforeSend` the alert will not display any data (when uncommented, obviously). At this point, I'd suspect that `data` isn't being populated appropriately, but Firebug shows the correct data in the request:
`server=1&maps%5B%5D=europe.tar.bz2`

Why is my request getting aborted?

Comment: I already commented on your previous post before, file upload cannot be done with `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed by Reigel, AJAX cannot handle file uploads. (I hadn't know that myself until a couple of days ago.)

There is, however a Javascript object which is able to handle a file upload and be interacted with using jQuery. NOTE: This is not AJAX, in a traditional sense of the word, but does bridge the gap you are currently dealing with.

[AJAX Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Comment: I'm partial to Jquery Form (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Granted, it's the only one I've used. It lets you upload stuff and remain on the page without a reload, which I'm guessing is the thing you (@Andy) seek.